# OCRA executables failing with --icon option

Tags: ruby, ocra

When I try to create an executable from my Ruby script with ocra's --icon option, the executable seems to compile correctly, but fails to run at execution.
The console gives me a

> FATAL ERROR: Invalid opcode '2343724299'.

I tried using different .ico files and the result is the same, **EXCEPT** the opcode is different.

Using the same script without the icon image yields an executable that executes perfectly fine.

Any ideas as to why?

Environment:
Ruby 1.9.3p448
Ocra 1.3.1
Windows 7 Professional, 64-bit